# How to select for multiple conditions to return one object that matches those conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, conditional-statements, instance

I am creating a test, and am trying to create a method that pulls a specific job posting ID when it matches the job posting title, the job type and the description, just in case that the case that there are more than one job posting with the same title.

I cannot get the `select` statement to pull the job posting ID out of the instance variable. Debugging shows that there is indeed the ID nested in the instance variable, but my conditions aren't being met because I am not doing it correctly.

`@job_posting` is the instance variable that contains the ID that I need, but I need my parameters in select to match so I can subsequently return the ID.

whenever I ONLY use posting title,such as:

```
target_postings = @job_postings.select{|posting|posting[:posting_title]}
```

it works and returns the ID I need, however I cannot do this:

```
def get_specific_posting_id_for_posting(posting_title, job_type, description)
  expect(@job_postings.length > 0)
  target_postings = @job_postings.select {|posting| posting[:posting_title] == posting_title; posting[:job_type] == job_type; posting[:description] == description}
  expect(target_postings.length == 1)
  target_posting = target_postings[0]
  posting_id = target_posting[:posting_id]
  posting_id
end
```

Comment: What is this method? Why are you using rspec methods is this a test? Side note your select should be joined by `&&` not `;` otherwise the only part that matters is `posting[:description] == description` but you need to be a lot clearer on what is actually going on here.

Comment: this is a test yes. i edited my answer to specify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like

```
target_postings = @job_postings.select {|posting| posting[:posting_title] == posting_title; posting[:job_type] == job_type; posting[:description] == description}
```

should probably be

```
target_postings = @job_postings.select do |posting| 
  posting[:posting_title] == posting_title 
    && posting[:job_type] == job_type 
    && posting[:description] == description
end
```

Your version has three separate checks, the first two of which do nothing, only the last statement in the block is actually being used to determine whether the item matches.

As an aside, since it looks like you only want the single first element that matches your conditions, you might want to consider using `find` instead of `select`. It works the same except it will stop iterating and return as soon as it finds the first matching item.

Comment: it looks like even with this, im still getting `nil` for `target_postings`. I verified that each item in the array does indeed have a value, but im not sure why its not returning the target posting

Comment: The advantage to `find` over `select` is it can be _MUCH_ faster.

Comment: @AA.Not much more I can suggest here but if you're still stuck I would recommend making use of debugging tools such as [pry](https://learn.co/lessons/debugging-with-pry) to halt execution inside your select and inspect your values to see exactly what's going on.